# Prevent a textbox from scrolling when adding text

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, textbox, scroll

I'm adding new logs line to a WinForms TextBox object, and this causes the textbox to scroll to the bottom. How can I prevent this and retain my current position? (a short code snippet would help)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SelectionStart didn't do what I want, for some reason. It got reset to 0.
I found [this post](http://vidmar.net/weblog/archive/2005/08/15/2092.aspx) that answers what I wanted (which was to use a textbox as a log). The answer is TextBox.AppendText()

Comment: The link looks to be bad.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, AppendText() won't do what you want (try adding more text and at some point it all goes awry)

The answer actually lies within the Win32 API, and luckily for us, a fellow SO user has already implemented this behavior perfectly: 
[Auto-scrolling text box uses more memory than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743448/auto-scrolling-text-box-uses-more-memory-than-expected-c-net-v3-5)

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can try `<yourTextBox>.Text += "your new text";` instead of `<yourTextBox>.AppendText("your new text");`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct and easy answer to the asked question is `SelectedText` (read/write) property. You can assign it some text and that text will appear at the caret position without necessarily scrolling the textbox. You can use `SelectionStart` before this to move the caret to the right place.